# Are there efficient ways to check if large numbers are prime

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

I was recently playing around in Python, and I wrote a program to check if a given number is prime. It works by checking to see if its divisible by each number other than 1 leading up to itself. It works well for small numbers but for very large numbers it takes a very very long time. I was wondering if there are programs that can see if a number is prime in a different and more efficient way.

Comment: Did you have a look on Wikipedia yet? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Comment: What do you call "very large numbers" exactly ?

Comment: Did you at least stop the search at the square root of the input number ? Though the method of successive divisions is quite poor, this criterion improves it significantly.